# Combining include and only:changes keywords in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a monorepo setup, and I would like to trigger a "sub" Pipeline when a specific folder changes. To keep things organized, I want to have these subfolders be responsible for their own CI pipelines & store their CI files inside and then `include` them in the root .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
root/
.gitlab-ci.yml
   foo/foo-ci.yml
   bar/bar-ci.yml
```

Is it possible to combine the `include` keyword with `only:changes:- foo/**/*`? Would I set the `only:` flag inside the sub CI files, or at the root CI file?

I've found examples of these features in isolation, I'm just not sure how I would combine them without creating a massive CI file in the root.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only keyword with respect to specific job. So it'll be in sub CI files where the actual procedure is written and not on the invoker file

So below will be my sub pipeline script where it runs only if a update happens on src folder

```
test_pylint:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.7
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - pip install pylint pylint-junit
    - pip install -e .
    - python -V
  script:
    - pylint --output-format=pylint_junit.JUnitReporter src/ | tee rspec.xml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - rspec.xml
    reports:
      junit: rspec.xml
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
  rules:
  - if: '($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop")'
    when: always
    changes:
      - src/*
```

Below is the root .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
  - test
include:
  - project: test
    file: /job/py-lint.gitlab-ci.yml
```

So all the only condition will be part of sub CI files alone

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Would you edit your answer to provide a brief CI file snippet that shows what you're suggesting?

Comment: Updated my answer. Instead of project options you'll be having local in your code as you're having sub CI files inside the same repo